# Prototyping the accessors of ALL POSSIBLE sub-properties

Tags: javascript, proxy, prototype, accessor, screeps

This is the code I'm starting with to prototype `goal` into the `Creep` class:

```
Object.defineProperty(
Creep.prototype,"goal",{
    set :function(value){
        this.memory.goal= value.id;
    },
    get :function() {
        return Game.getObjectById(this.memory.goal);
    },
}
)
```

Now let's suppose I want `Creep.goal` not to contain a single value, but multiple values instead, and let every single sub-properties of `Creep.goal` have the foresaid accessors.
(So I can easily store multiple game objects into the creep's memory)

These properties are meant to be added at runtime, so I *do not* know how many there will be nor their names, thus I can't simply copy-paste this code once for every property I'd like there to be.

How should I proceed in order to define the accessors of *all possible* properties-to-be of an object ?

**----- SOLUTION -----**

So I was suggested to use a `Proxy` for this. It was a completely new concept to me and I've hit a lot of walls, but I got something to work like I wanted !

```
// Prototyping goal as a proxy
Object.defineProperty(
    Creep.prototype,"goal",{
        get :function()
            {return new Proxy(this.memory.goal, objectInMemory) }
    }
)

// Proxy's Handler (my previous accessors)
const objectInMemory= {
    set(goal, property, value){
        goal[property] = value.id;
        return true;
    },
    get(goal, property){
        return Game.getObjectById(goal[property]);
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're aiming for, but if the properties are truly dynamic and have to be evaluated at runtime there are [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects that are supported by Screeps' runtime.

What this does is it allows you to programmatically intercept all of the messages for an object, including accessing properties.

Comment: I never heard of proxy's before, but it sounds interesting. I'll get into it and get back to you later.

Comment: I omitted most of the screeps background to try not to wander away from the point, but to put it back on context: I had made a set of accessor that'd help me store and recover game objects into/from a creep's memory without having to type roomObject.id or Game.getObjectById() every single time.